# std::map (Enum / CString) is triggering a memory leak in my app - why?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, c-strings, stdmap

I have looked at similar discussions ([std::map causing memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8376670/2287576)) about this issue but according to the debug build of my app this is triggering a memory leak:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SetLocale(LanguageMSA eLang)
{
    // See: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx#ISO2

    map<LanguageMSA, CString> mapLocales;

    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Afrikaans, _T("af"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Albanian, _T("sqi"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Arabic, _T("ara"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Aukan, _T("drk"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Bulgarian, _T("bgr"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::ChineseSimplified, _T("chs"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Croatian, _T("hrv"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Czech, _T("csy"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Danish, _T("dan"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Dutch, _T("nld"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::English, _T("eng"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Estonian, _T("et"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Finnish, _T("fin"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::French, _T("fra"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::German, _T("deu"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Greek, _T("ell"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Gujarati, _T("guj"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Hindi, _T("hin"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Hungarian, _T("hu-HU"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Indonesian, _T("ind"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Italian, _T("ita"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Japanese, _T("jpn"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Lingala, _T("ln-CG"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Maltese, _T("mt-MT"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Polish, _T("plk"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::PortugueseBrazil, _T("ptb"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::PortuguesePortugal, _T("pt-PT"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Punjabi, _T("pa"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Romanian, _T("rom"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Russian, _T("rus"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Saramaccan, _T("fra")); // Special case (uses French)
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Setswana, _T("tn-ZA"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Slovenian, _T("slv"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Spanish, _T("esp"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Swahili, _T("swk"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Swedish, _T("sve"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Tagalog, _T("fil-PH"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Tamil, _T("tai"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Tsonga, _T("tso"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Turkish, _T("trk"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Ukrainian, _T("ukr"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Vietnamese, _T("vit"));
    mapLocales.emplace(LanguageMSA::Zulu, _T("zu-ZA"));

    CString strLocale = _T("eng"); // Default (also used by some "partial" translations

    if (mapLocales.find(eLang) != mapLocales.end())
        strLocale = mapLocales[eLang];

    _tsetlocale(LC_ALL, strLocale);
}
```

Please advise if there is anything I need to do to stop this memory leak being listed when the debug version closes. Or is it a red herring in this case?

---

`LanguageMSA` is an `enum class`:

```
enum class LanguageMSA
{
    English = 0,
    German,
    Spanish,
    Italian,
    Polish,
    French,
    PortugueseBrazil,
    Dutch,
    Swedish,
    Slovenian,
    Czech,
    Finnish,
    Danish,
    Ukrainian,
    Russian,
    Tagalog,
    HaitianCreole,
    Afrikaans,
    Albanian,
    ChineseSimplified,
    Croatian,
    Turkish,
    Twi,
    Swahili,    // AJT v11.3.4
    Estonian,   // AJT v12.0.5
    Romanian,   // AJT v12.0.8
    Greek,      // AJT v13.0.0
    Bulgarian,  // AJT v13.0.2
    Malagasy,   // AJT v14.0.4‏
    Arabic,     // AJT v16.0.0
    Indonesian, // AJT v16.0.2
    Hindi,      // AJT v16.0.7
    Tamil,      // AJT v16.1.0
    Vietnamese, // AJT v16.1.1
    Zulu,       // AJT v16.1.6
    Gun,        // AJT v17.0.9
    Lingala,    // AJT v17.0.9
    PortuguesePortugal, // AJT v17.1.0
    Punjabi,    // AJT v17.1.3
    Maltese,    // AJT v17.2.3
    Hungarian,  // AJT v17.2.6
    Saramaccan, // AJT v18.0.0
    Amharic,    // AJT v18.0.6
    Japanese,   // AJT v18.0.6
    Setswana,   // AJT v18.0.8
    Sranantongo,// AJT v18.1.4
    Aukan,      // AJT v18.1.6
    Armenian,   // AJT v18.2.1
    Gujarati,   // AJT v19.0.9
    Sesotho,    // AJT v20.0.3
    Cebuano,    // AJT v20.1.2
    Tsonga,     // AJT v20.1.5
    PidginWestAfrica,   // AJT v20.3.0

    // Maintain a count of language enums
    Count

} ;
```

---

Memory leak dump:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{104257} normal block at 0x0000028AC8015830, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 
{104255} normal block at 0x0000028AC8015210, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 
{104253} normal block at 0x0000028AC706A920, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        (R ÈŠ   > 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 52 01 C8 8A 02 00 00 
{104244} normal block at 0x0000028AE311F820, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
{104242} normal block at 0x0000028AE311EEC0, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
{104241} normal block at 0x0000028AC706A0B0, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        Øî ãŠ   > 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D8 EE 11 E3 8A 02 00 00 
{104232} normal block at 0x0000028AC80152F0, 38 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 
{104230} normal block at 0x0000028AC6CF9690, 54 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0E 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 
{104229} normal block at 0x0000028AC7069C00, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        ¨–ÏÆŠ   > 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A8 96 CF C6 8A 02 00 00 
{104220} normal block at 0x0000028AC8015DE0, 42 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 
{104218} normal block at 0x0000028AC6CF8F10, 58 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 
{104217} normal block at 0x0000028AC706B280, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        ( ÏÆŠ   > 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 8F CF C6 8A 02 00 00 
{104208} normal block at 0x0000028AC80151A0, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
{104206} normal block at 0x0000028AC80164E0, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
{104204} normal block at 0x0000028AC706B910, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        ød ÈŠ   > 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 64 01 C8 8A 02 00 00 
{104195} normal block at 0x0000028AC8016A20, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 
{104193} normal block at 0x0000028AC8014560, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 
{104191} normal block at 0x0000028AC706A830, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        xE ÈŠ   > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 45 01 C8 8A 02 00 00 
{103563} normal block at 0x0000028AC80157C0, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 
{103561} normal block at 0x0000028AC8013B50, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 
{103559} normal block at 0x0000028AC706B820, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        h; ÈŠ   > 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 68 3B 01 C8 8A 02 00 00 
{103550} normal block at 0x0000028AC7090340, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
{103548} normal block at 0x0000028AC7090DC0, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
{103547} normal block at 0x0000028AC706B730, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        Ø   ÇŠ   > 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D8 0D 09 C7 8A 02 00 00 
{103538} normal block at 0x0000028AC8016BE0, 38 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 
{103536} normal block at 0x0000028AC6CF8E90, 54 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0E 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 
{103535} normal block at 0x0000028AC706A290, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        ¨ŽÏÆŠ   > 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A8 8E CF C6 8A 02 00 00 
{103526} normal block at 0x0000028AC80169B0, 42 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 
{103524} normal block at 0x0000028AC6CF8D10, 58 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 
{103523} normal block at 0x0000028AC706A380, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        ( ÏÆŠ   > 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 8D CF C6 8A 02 00 00 
{103514} normal block at 0x0000028AC8015F30, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
{103512} normal block at 0x0000028AC8013FB0, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
{103510} normal block at 0x0000028AC706A650, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        È? ÈŠ   > 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C8 3F 01 C8 8A 02 00 00 
{103501} normal block at 0x0000028AC8013CA0, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 
{103499} normal block at 0x0000028AC8013760, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 
{103497} normal block at 0x0000028AC706BA00, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        x7 ÈŠ   > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 37 01 C8 8A 02 00 00 
{101036} normal block at 0x0000028AC8013990, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 
{101034} normal block at 0x0000028AC8014640, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 
{101032} normal block at 0x0000028AC706B190, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        XF ÈŠ   > 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 58 46 01 C8 8A 02 00 00 
{101023} normal block at 0x0000028AE311F700, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
{101021} normal block at 0x0000028AE311E5C0, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
{101020} normal block at 0x0000028AC706A740, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        Øå ãŠ   > 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D8 E5 11 E3 8A 02 00 00 
{101011} normal block at 0x0000028AC8013680, 38 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 
{101009} normal block at 0x0000028AC6CDEA80, 54 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0E 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 
{101008} normal block at 0x0000028AC706A560, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <         êÍÆŠ   > 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 98 EA CD C6 8A 02 00 00 
{100999} normal block at 0x0000028AC8015050, 42 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 
{100997} normal block at 0x0000028AC6CDF900, 58 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 
{100996} normal block at 0x0000028AC706ADD0, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <         ùÍÆŠ   > 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 F9 CD C6 8A 02 00 00 
{100987} normal block at 0x0000028AC80135A0, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
{100985} normal block at 0x0000028AC8014FE0, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
{100983} normal block at 0x0000028AC706B0A0, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        øO ÈŠ   > 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 4F 01 C8 8A 02 00 00 
{100974} normal block at 0x0000028AC80145D0, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 
{100972} normal block at 0x0000028AC8014480, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 
{100970} normal block at 0x0000028AC706B460, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <         D ÈŠ   > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 98 44 01 C8 8A 02 00 00 
{12591} normal block at 0x0000028AC64B5970, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 
{12589} normal block at 0x0000028AC64B5740, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 
{12587} normal block at 0x0000028AC7F8D9D0, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        XWKÆŠ   > 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 58 57 4B C6 8A 02 00 00 
{12578} normal block at 0x0000028AC7F06DB0, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
{12576} normal block at 0x0000028AC7F07830, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
{12575} normal block at 0x0000028AC7F8D8E0, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        HxðÇŠ   > 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 78 F0 C7 8A 02 00 00 
{12566} normal block at 0x0000028AC64B5890, 38 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 
{12564} normal block at 0x0000028AC6496AE0, 54 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0E 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 
{12563} normal block at 0x0000028AC7F8D7F0, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        øjIÆŠ   > 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 6A 49 C6 8A 02 00 00 
{12554} normal block at 0x0000028AC64B5820, 42 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 
{12552} normal block at 0x0000028AC64965E0, 58 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 
{12551} normal block at 0x0000028AC7F8E240, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        øeIÆŠ   > 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 65 49 C6 8A 02 00 00 
{12542} normal block at 0x0000028AC64B4E10, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
{12540} normal block at 0x0000028AC64B53C0, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
{12538} normal block at 0x0000028AC7F8D610, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        ØSKÆŠ   > 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D8 53 4B C6 8A 02 00 00 
{12529} normal block at 0x0000028AC64B4D30, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 
{12527} normal block at 0x0000028AC64B4C50, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < 3#^ö           > 00 33 23 5E F6 7F 00 00 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 
{12525} normal block at 0x0000028AC7EE7740, 168 bytes long.
 Data: <        hLKÆŠ   > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 68 4C 4B C6 8A 02 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

Comment: That's not going to cause leak, something else is going on. You also have `using namespace std` somewhere (not recommended) or `using std::map`. It's better to not rely on that. Just declare `std::map<Type1, Type2> mymap;`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I just tweaked the code for the usage of `using std::map`. I now realise that the dumpo values change each time. So this is hard for me to track.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I am not sure how to detect these errors now since the values change every time and are not fixed.

Comment: `std::map<int, CStringA> m; m.emplace(123, "xy"); if (m.find(123) != m.end()) print...` is the minimum version of your code, it's correct and it doesn't cause leak. Your report shows repeat sizes 168, 40, 34, etc., you may have an array of some containers with those sizes, or there is data corruption elsewhere.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I remember I moved some tidy up code from destructors to OnDestroy. I now realise that some of those dialog classes I make an instance of to get info. But since I don’t display them, their OnDestroy won’t call. I will look at that first.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Confirmed. Re-instated the destructor for a specific class. Memory leak resolved.